# How to restrict the caller of the function from passing concatenated strings in Haskell?

Tags: sql, haskell

I am checking out a haskell client library for mysql called [mysql-simple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mysql-simple) by Bryan O'Sullivan. The library doesn't allow the user to use concatenated strings as queries.

The following works fine:

```
myQuery :: Query
myQuery = "SELECT id, name FROM users LIMIT 1"
```

However, this fails:

```
myQuery :: Query
myQuery = "SELECT id, name FROM users LIMIT 1" ++ ""
```

This is the error that I get when running the following example:

```
do
  rows <- (query_ connection myQuery) :: IO [( Int , String)]
...


• Couldn't match expected type ‘Query’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
• In the expression: "SELECT id, name FROM users LIMIT 1" ++ ""
  In an equation for ‘myQuery’:
      myQuery = "SELECT id, name FROM users LIMIT 1" ++ ""
```

My question is **what makes this restriction possible?**

I can see from the [source code](https://github.com/paul-rouse/mysql-simple/blob/master/Database/MySQL/Simple/Types.hs#L40) that this is intentional, but I am unable to understand the basic concept behind it. Is is because the `Query` type is not an instance of a typeclass that `String` is? Also, even if I concatenate the string, shouldn't the type checker infer that the resultant string can be used as a `Query`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it does allow concatenated strings as queries. You just need to use a concatenation operator that operates on queries:

```
myQuery :: Query
myQuery = "SELECT id, name FROM users LIMIT 1" <> ""
```

The `(++)` operator is specific to lists, whereas `(<>)` works with any `Monoid` (and `Query` is an instance of `Monoid` but is not a list type).

And to answer your other question: a `String` can never be used as a `Query`. I suspect the belief that it can came from the `OverloadedStrings` extension, which lets you write string *literals* and have them be interpreted as types other than `String` by implicitly applying `fromString` to them. So, e.g.

```
foo = "foo"
```

would actually be short for `foo = fromString "foo"`. So imagine working without the extension, and you can see the difference between these two:

```
foo1 = fromString "bar" ++ fromString "baz"
foo2 = fromString ("bar" ++ "baz")
```

The former corresponds to what you wrote; the latter corresponds to what you meant.

Comment: (Note: untested. I just referred to the docs, I didn't install the package and actually check that this works.)

Comment: After seeing your response, I realized that I could've used `mappend` as the source also shows it. The operator can also be used if `Data.Monoid` is imported. Also, your comment about overloaded strings is correct. I should've clarified that in the question but your answer explains what I wanted to find out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mandark Yes, `mappend` and `(<>)` are synonyms, given the right imports.